# console.log results in Anvil output

Tags: logs, foundry, console

I am using the library `forge-std/console.sol` in a contract for debugging purposes and execute the corresponding functions on a local Anvil network. I use Cast to send the transaction to the network.
When I check the log of the Anvil network after the execution of a function that uses `console.log`, I see several outputs after the RPC method `eth_estimateGas`. Why is it printed that many times? My expectation was that each log is only printed once after RPC method `eth_sendRawTransaction`, which it actually does. Can someone explain these multiple logs?

Here is an example of the Anvil logs. In the corresponding function, I invoke `console.log` as follows: `console.log("test")`.

```
eth_chainId
eth_getTransactionCount
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_feeHistory
eth_estimateGas
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
eth_sendRawTransaction
test

    Transaction: 0x2b34a07537cab325612afa9d7f2b5b02c5ff3c39e7a79cc8a0d44bb3619f59dd
    Gas used: 29468

    Block Number: 6
    Block Hash: 0x2c5c2fe53bb48aa2eae42100ac05462b503f9d54e68ef9f021aabd24e50d43a6
    Block Time: "Thu, 31 Aug 2023 08:17:00 +0000"

eth_getTransactionReceipt
```